# what is the use of partition in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I could not comprehend in Kafka documentation is what is the exact need of partitioning a topic? What is the issue if it were only one topic with no partition (or one partition only).

Answer (score 0):

Topics require partitions, even if there is one

Partitions are the unit of parallelization and ordering for Kafka. If you have one partition, then all events are strictly ordered (by insert time). That is a valid use-case, not an "issue".

Kafka records can be considered key-value tuples. The producers will hash any non-null keys and route them to the same partitions. So, for example, if you have userIds and have events like "user create/update/delete", then all same events will arrive to the same partition for that user, so they can be processed in order (you cannot update or delete without first creating). But not all users need to arrive to the same partition, so you can parallelize that processing to hundreds or thousands of partitions for any such "user-events" topic.

For null keys in the Kafka record, then events are round-robin distributed over all partitions, and your consumers have no guarantee in what order those events will be read (again, unless there is one partition). This is useful for standard messaging where you just want to know *something happened*, but don't require historical context of that event. You add more partitions when lots of events are happening, and you want to be able to consume them more quickly.

Consumers in a consumer group can only be assigned one partition at a time. As an example - if you want to quickly process 1 million  events, then you could have 100K events spread over 100 partitions and process that in parallel with 100 consumers, rather than 1 consumer waiting to process 1M events all by itself.